# Failed connection in MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, connection, mongovue, database

I'm trying to create a new connection in MongoVUE but I have an error : **"Connection was refused"**.

The connection configuration is:

1. Name: database
2. Server: 127.0.0.1
3. Port: 27017(default)
4. Username:admin

> Connection was refused Unable to connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. Type:
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException Stack:    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan
>   timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Connect(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Connect()    at
>   MangoUI.MMongo.QSDlL5xzK686iCExThO(Object )    at
>   MangoUI.MMongo.Open(Boolean mustWrite)    at MangoUI.MMongo.Open()
>   at MangoUI.MConnection.get_IsValid()    at
>   MangoUI.WinConnect.SCOjR9kYRPerNNngykW(Object )    at
>   MangoUI.WinConnect.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Type:
>   System.NullReferenceException Stack:    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.RefreshStateAsSoonAsPossible()
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.HandleException(Exception
>   ex)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer,
>   Int32 requestId)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage
>   message)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection
>   connection)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](MongoConnection
>   connection, String databaseName, IMongoCommand command)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Ping(MongoConnection connection)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan
>   timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)

How can I fix it and create connection? Help please.

Comment: MongoDB 3.X server perhaps? The authentication routines have been updated. Make sure your client supports these. Therefore upgrade or use something else.

Comment: I've installed server earlier and it works fine... I'll check my client. What tools can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have solved this problem.I just provide how I solve for whom come with it later:

1. **check  if your mongodb is on.** 
   Open the browser, input the url`localhost:27017`, you should find that the web page have words like"it seems that you attend to connect the mongodb", then go to step 3. 

   If not go to step 2.
2. **keep your mongodb on**. 
   you should add the install directory to the path variable. 
   Then create a directory to store you db,for example"D:\data\db\". 
   Then input this command`mongod --dbpath D:\data\db` in the console, **never close the console if you want to make connection**. 
   Then go step 3.
3. **Use MongoBooster rather than MongVUE**. MongoVUE is nolooger update since 2014. However, mongobooster is well and good,support mongodb from 2.2 to 3.2

That is all.